# How to make the flex item text wrapped under the adjutants item

Tags: css, flexbox, styling

How to get the text wrapped under the points?

https://codepen.io/neginbasiri/pen/ZEGReRZ

```
<div class="pointLine__PointLine-wgyo1p-1 bUhvVh">
  <svg class="icon--icon--base--17 pointLine__RooIcon-wgyo1p-0 iBQvHK">IMAGE</svg>
  <div class="pointLine__Content-wgyo1p-2 cPwDGx"><div class="pointLine__Point-wgyo1p-3 
pointLine__DefaultPoint-wgyo1p-4 enMiay">16,000</div><p class="Text__StyledText-zy9rxk-0 dufgDt"> 
Points when you join or switch&nbsp;<span id="super-node-187"><sup class="super--super--root--13"> 
<span>3</span></sup> </span></p></div>
```

In the example switch should show under 16,000.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bUhvVh {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;

}

.iBQvHK {
    color: #e40000;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20px;
}

.icon--icon--base--17 {
    height: 1em;
    min-width: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.cPwDGx {
    font-family: Ciutadella Regular;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.enMiay {
    float: left;
    font-family: Ciutadella Medium;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    color: #323232;
}

.dufgDt {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Ciutadella Regular',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="pointLine__PointLine-wgyo1p-1 bUhvVh">
  <svg class="icon--icon--base--17 pointLine__RooIcon-wgyo1p-0 iBQvHK">IMAGE</svg>
  <div class="pointLine__Content-wgyo1p-2 cPwDGx"><div class="pointLine__Point-wgyo1p-3 pointLine__DefaultPoint-wgyo1p-4 enMiay">16,000</div><p class="Text__StyledText-zy9rxk-0 dufgDt"> Points when you join or switch&nbsp;<span id="super-node-187"><sup class="super--super--root--13"><span>3</span></sup> </span></p></div>
  
</div>
```

1. Remove `display: flex; flex: 1` from `.cPwDGx`.
2. Remove `display: inline-block` from `.enMiay` and add `float: left` for this element.
3. Update `width` to `min-width` for `icon--icon--base--17`. It will not shrink if text is larger.

Refer : https://codepen.io/bala_tamizh/pen/WNvyEPg